# Absolute value around numbers Example: $y = 2|x + 2|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, arithmetic, absolute-value

I know this is a super basic question but I can't find an answer.  Is it that the result of anything within the absolute value, $|\,|$, must be evaluated first and given a positive value?

I knew this years ago but I've forgotten.  So for...
\begin{align*}
y & = 2|x + 2|, \quad \text{where }x = -3\\
\Rightarrow \quad y & = 2.
\end{align*}

Correct?

Comment: Yes. It's right!

Comment: Ok - so implies same order of operations as parenthesis, but result must be evaluated as positive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you must first evaluate the value of expression in the `||` (which named absolute) and then if the value is negative multiply it by -1

see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must evaluate what is inside of the absolute value symbols first, and then just use the *magnitude* of that value.

Hence, in algebra, say,$$|x + 2| = \frac{y}{2}$$can have two possibilities:$$x + 2 = \frac{y}{2}$$and$$-x - 2 = \frac{y}{2}.$$

Be careful of this you must. (This wasn't your question, but I thought that this point was important to address.)